# Unable to deploy web site to Azure "String larger than expected"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I have deployed to Azure Web sites several times from Visual Studio but since some weeks ago I can't deploy anymore. I get this error over and over again

> Web deployment task failed. (Error deserializing string. String larger
>   than expected.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FAILED_TO_DESERIALIZE.)

I have no clue how to solve this (Seems impossible to find anything online either). I can deploy via FTP. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2015, update 1.

EDIT 2: I created a new deployment slot and deployed to that one. After that I did a VIP swap and now I can deploy to both instances. I still have no clue why it didn't work before.

Comment: Are your Azure web app built with ASP.NET 5 or below?

Comment: One interesting test: if you deploy to a test Azure Web App instead of your real one, does the same issue occur? That may help isolate the nature of the issue.

Comment: @juvchan it's built with .net target framework 4.5.

Comment: @DavidEbbo If I create a new deplopyment slot and deployt it to the new empty slot it works. Also, if I deploy to my local file system it works.

Comment: It's puzzling. It means that the issue is more with the state of the Web App than with what you're deploying. I see one instance of this issue [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/2069829.aspx?vNext+publish+wwwroot+Error+deserializing+string+String+larger+than+expected+), but there was no follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error when deploying a website to the Free Azure App Service Tier (F1). We're using .NET Framework 4.6 using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

To work around the error I scaled up the App Service to Production (S1) then the web deployment was successful. I could then scale it back to F1.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish to azure web server, I think the number of files you can publish at one time is limited.

Try to publish lower than 1024 files at a time. (this is not exact number though..)

** You can publish by folders or even by files.

This tip is for free subscription plan, I am not sure about other plans.